# header.php file generating random string at end of URL in location bar

Tags: php, url, wordpress-theming

I'm developing a heavily redesigned a WordPress theme, including layout, templates and functions and for some reason the header.php file is now generating a random string and appending it to every URL on my domain after a hash tag like this:

http://www.pixelsandtea.com/#axzz1ZvQRmIcj

I've narrowed down the problem to the header file by deactivating all plugins, and when I reverted the header.php file back to the original it didn't do it anymore. I'd just like to know if anybody's aware of a similar problem and what might be the cause so I can keep my redesigned header with a fix for the problem.

Thanks

Comment: What's in the `header.php`, if you don't mind me asking? I can't guess its contents ;)

Comment: For what I see on the source you have a lot of javascript, try removing them one by one. Also what is the purpose of metatags editURI&wlwmanifest

Comment: @hakre - what javascript files are you using? Maybe if you're using the same or similar to mine then we can both narrow down the root of the issue.

Comment: @derp - did you see that editURI&wlwmanifest bit in my main page's code? Because I did a search through and couldn't find it, though either way, I'm not sure what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not PHP; it's javascript - you surely noticed how, with javascript turned off, it does not happen.

Look for some instances of `window.location.hash` in the plethora of js files you're using. There's quite a few but hint: the one you're looking for is not in jQuery.js.

Other hint: wht's that javascript file that has a lot to do with internal anchors?

Comment: This is true. FYI, I'm currently using about 3 plugins which load their own js files, and most of those are from external domains. However, as I stated in my original question, I know that this problem is not caused by a plugin as I had deactivated those already, though I have now reactivated them.

Comment: @Ben: to search among all the dybnamically loaded js (in chrome): left click anywhere, chose "inspect element"; click on the "resources" tab; select "scripts" from the dropdown on the left; search "hash". You'll find all the scripts having to dso with the url hash.

Comment: It's specifically the "Tynt Publishing" part of my custom script file, I've removed it and will look for an alternative. Thanks for the Chrome tip btw @cbrandolino

Answer (score 3):

I was so freaked out and perplexed by this problem and it turned out to be being caused by the 'AddThis' code.

If you check the option "Track address bar shares" while getting the code, this happens. If you uncheck it the problem is solved.

BTW it is unchecked by default and I had checked it.